# Numerical Results with replacement rules

Tags: numerical-value

Why are the following outputs different?

```
N[(x^2 + y^2) /. Thread[{x, y} -> {1., 1.}], 10]
```

gives 2..

```
N[(1^2 + 1^2), 10]
```

gives 2.000000000.

How can I use replacement but still retain numerical precision?

Answer (score 2):

Once you've lost precision, you cannot get it back.  Use

```
N[(x^2 + y^2) /. Thread[{x, y} -> {1, 1}], 10]
```

or

```
(x^2 + y^2) /. Thread[{x, y} -> {1`10, 1`10}]
```